# Foreach select based in two tables MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

So the question is very simple, I have this two tables (TAble A and Table B). 
I'm gonna show what I need to get with this two tables.

**Pseudocode**

I need to Select from tableA all rows with **idadmin** = 3 
    and from tableB all result that matches with **idadmin** 3 and all the related rows that **orderId** gets from tableA .

This image describe a little my question.

**TableA (Order)**
[image: Table A]

**TableB (Detail)**

[image: Table B]

TableB (Detail)
Is there a way to do this in a query ?
Can I do with PHP & MYSQL ?

**EDIT:**

Maybe with 2 queries ?

The first one getting all the rows that matches with idadmin = 3
then another one that gimme all rows that match with id admin=3 and all orderId from the table ( in java I do this with a foreach )
This two tables its a sort of "**Several Orders and a detail of this Orders".**

**What I expect from this query**

```
Order 1
Order 2
Order 3
.
.
.
DetailOrder 1
DetailOrder 2
DetailOrder 3
```

Thanks in advance to all. And Thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't understand your pseudocode. Could you show the desired result as a table?

Comment: It sounds like it's just a `JOIN`, but it's hard to tell from your question.

Comment: what is your expected result? it would better if you provide original tables name. sometime it could help us to understand what is going on.

Comment: @Barmar and for me it sounds more like `UNION ALL` :-) to get all orderid(1,2,3,4,5)

Comment: Is not a UNION or  a JOIN what I need.

Comment: you can't do it with sql query, sql query return set of rows with the same structure of each row. And generally it is `LEFT JOIN` head of order is left table and details of each order is right table.

Comment: With PHP ? 
If I do a query for every Detail table for every order is to heavy I think.